# CircleCI using different repos and same workflow

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I want 2 jobs,

```
jobA: to checkout and build repository A, save output to workspace X
```

then

```
jobB: to attach to workspace X, checkout and build repository B with the output of jobA
```

How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[CircleCI Docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/) is your friend. So I'll let you look through there for the specific config keys.

From the perspective of building repository A:

- If repository B is private, you'll need to create an SSH key to be used as a checkout key, add it on GitHub to repository B, and then add it on CircleCI to repository A's settings
- There's only a single Workspace during a build. So add what you need to the workspace from Job A, and then you'll be able to retrieve it in Job B.
- For Job B, you'll do a normal run step with a `git clone` to get the repository B code. I would be careful with where you clone this and the paths for Workspaces. Might want to start with some debug `ls -lah` commands to make sure everything is laid out in the filesystem as you expect them to be.